# The code "from sportsreference.fb" is not recognised

Tags: python, api, module, syntax-error

I wanted to access some football data for Chelsea FC from this site https://github.com/roclark/sportsreference. I successfully installed sportsreference on python:

```
pip install sportsreference
```

However, I am not able to access the football data for any team (Tottenham, Chelsea etc.)

```
from sportsreference.fb.team import Team

Chelsea = Team('Chelsea')
print(Chelsea.goals_scored)
```

I get an error: [No module named 'sportsreference.fb']
The code for all the other sports works, just not the football.

What code can I use to fix this and access the football data?